# VBA - Looking for row number in another file

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to find a cell containing certain value in a different, closed file from where I am running my code. Once I find it, I want to receive the row number of said cell. Somehow my code won't work. It is a mixture of stuff I have found on this site and things I have coded myself. Any help would be great!

```
    Dim file_dir As Workbook
Set file_dir = Workbooks.Open("PATH.xlsx")

Dim j As Integer
Dim n As Integer
Dim temp As Range

n = file_dir.ActiveSheet.Cells(file_dir.ActiveSheet.Cells.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

Set temp = file_dir.ActiveSheet.Range("A1:A" & n).Find(what:="LOOKUP_VALUE")
j = temp.Row

MsgBox j
```

Comment: for workbooks.open you have to give the full path of the file, not just the name

Comment: I have hardcoded the full path ("C:\...). That's what I meant by path. Sorry for the misunderstanding

Comment: is the file opened successfully? what line does not work?

Comment: `j=temp.row` 
That line is not working. the excel error says something about a with block, so no clue

Comment: Probably "LOOKUP_VALUE" is not found so it cannot return the row.

Comment: I am sure it is there, since I am using just a dummy file, until I get my code straight.

Comment: Can you provide a sample? are you sure the lookup value exists in the sheet?

Comment: Have you stepped through the code to see what's happening? If temp is Nothing then the term is not found.

Comment: The error is error 91: variable object or with block not established. I am sure it is there, I create the dummy file myself. I have stepped through the code copying it in another sheet, beacuse it is in the middle of a userform and I couldn't find the way to step it i there withouth triggering other events, and I find temp=Nothing when I know the lookup value is there

Comment: When using Find it's advisable to specify all or at least some of the other parameters because you might be matching e.g. whole/partial contents without knowing it.

Comment: `Set temp = file_dir.ActiveSheet.Range("A2:A" & n).Find(what:=box_numeroOT.Value, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)`
something likes this? I am trying to look for numbers, 0001, 0002 and so on

Comment: Is it a number 1 formatted as "0001" and if so you should search for 1. Also look for trailing and leading spaces. Hard to know without seeing your data.

Comment: That was the key! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to Stack Overflow, I can see you are a beginner so I thought I would show a different way of solving this. You need to learn the data types and what functions return so I think instead of using nested functions etc it is better to start off with a simpler code and then you can make it more sophisticated by making it run faster etc. It seems your value is in column A so instead of using `FIND` just loop and compare it to your `lookup_value`. Make sure that you give the `lookup_value` a real value inside the routine:

```
Sub Main()
    Dim bValueFound As Boolean
    Dim j As Integer
    Dim n As Integer
    Dim temp As Range
    Dim WS As Worksheet
    Dim file_dir As Workbook

    Set file_dir = Workbooks.Open("PATH.xlsx")
    Set WS = file_dir.ActiveSheet
    n = WS.Cells(WS.Cells.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    Set temp = file_dir.ActiveSheet.Range("A1:A" & n)

    For j = 1 To n
        If WS.Cells(j, 1).Value = LOOKUP_VALUE Then
            bValueFound = True
            Exit For
        End If
    Next j

    If bValueFound Then
        MsgBox "The row is " & j
    Else
        MsgBox "Lookup value was not found"
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks! this is great, since my aim is to do this using two search criteria at once, and the if block allows me to use two logical conditions easily. However, it is not working, while my first code now works when I specify the lookat and lookin parameters

Comment: My first code returns The row is 2, and my lookup value is in A2. The code you provided returns "lookup value was not found"

Comment: It is hard to guess where the problem is without a sample data or uploading your excel file. This could be due to data type, for example the data pasted in your sheet could be text while you have given your lookup_value a number. If you upload your file and I can see the data, I would fix both codes for you easily

Comment: You were right, as the problem is related with data type. My lookup values are numbers formatted as "0000" with `format("my_number","0000")`. I tried hardcoding 1 instead of a variable called lookup_valu with my formatted "0001" value inside, and it worked! Thanks!!

Comment: feel free to select this as the right answer, upper left checkmark and the upvote

Comment: Done the uptovote, thanks for pointing the correct answer checkmark!

Comment: @FFG the upvote is the little triangle above and below the checkmark, in this forum you have to always give feedbacks about answers comments etc. The forum is based on reputation so the more you put efforts to help others the more you will get badges and reputation and this way the more you will have access to features.

Comment: Great! Thanks for the welcoming! I will be putting a lot of effort into the community. Upvote doesn't show due to my low reputation, but it is still recorded.